# How can I optimize the kernel start up time by analyzing output of OProfile?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, oprofile

I am trying to reduce the time it takes for the kernel to start up i.e the time it takes from selecting the kernel option in GRUB to the start of init(). I have used OProfile tool to profile my customized kernel. How do I proceed with it's output?

Comment: You question is too broad and too open ended.

Comment: Usually you don't need OProfile for kernel boot time optimizations. See these links: [link1](http://elinux.org/Boot_Time), [link2](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Optimize_Linux_Boot_Time), [link3 (see Alexandre Belloni presentation)](http://free-electrons.com/blog/elce-2012-videos/)

Answer (score 0):

OProfile is not the best option for this.

The best option is to get the [bootgraph.pl](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/scripts/bootgraph.pl) script, run the kernel with the `initcall_debug` boot parameter and then process the output with something like `dmesg | perl bootgraph.pl > ~/boot-time.svg`